# remove extra strings from file

Tags: python, string, file, text

Is there any wany to remove the date and heartrate : from the result and them save them in file

> 2022.12.08 14:49:55 Heartrate  : -1
> 2022.12.08 14:49:55 Resting Agitation Score  : -1
> 2022.12.08 14:49:56 Heartrate  : -1
> 2022.12.08 14:49:56 Resting Agitation Score  : -1
> 2022.12.08 14:49:57 Heartrate  : -1
> 2022.12.08 14:49:57 Resting Agitation Score  : -1
> 2022.12.08 14:49:58 Heartrate  : 32
> 2022.12.08 14:49:58 Resting Agitation Score  : -1
> 2022.12.08 14:49:59 Heartrate  : 31
> 2022.12.08 14:49:59 Resting Agitation Score  : -1
> 2022.12.08 14:50:00 Heartrate  : 32
> 2022.12.08 14:50:00 Resting Agitation Score  : -1
> 2022.12.08 14:50:01 Heartrate  : -1
> 2022.12.08 14:50:01 Resting Agitation Score  : -1
> 2022.12.08 14:50:02 Heartrate  : -1
> 2022.12.08 14:50:02 Resting Agitation Score  : -1
> 2022.12.08 14:50:03 Heartrate  : -1
> 2022.12.08 14:50:03 Resting Agitation Score  : -1

### I want output as

### -1

### -1

### -1

### -1

-1

Comment: which type your input is ?

Comment: The answer is: Yes, there is a way. You can start implementing. Please come back if you face a particular issue that you can't solve. I wonder how the result -1, -1, -1 would be useful, but well ...

Comment: @R. Baraiya its text not image

Comment: @Thomas Weller I a wondering how i can do that

Comment: @NehaDurani still not clear your input, is it dict, list or df  or just sring ?

Comment: How does nine lines of input boil down to three lines of output?

Comment: it is data coming live from a sensor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to consider a regular expression for getting the score

```py
import re

sensor_input = '2022.12.08 14:49:55 Heartrate : -1 2022.12.08 14:49:55 Resting Agitation Score : -1'

# Find and extract score
match_ = re.search('Resting Agitation Score : (-?\d*)', sensor_input)

int(match_.group(1)) # returns -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input is in a text file you could read the whole file as string into a variable and do something like this:

```
 input_string = """2022.12.08 14:49:55 Heartrate : -1 2022.12.08 14:49:55 Resting Agitation Score : -1
     2022.12.08 14:49:56 Heartrate : -1 2022.12.08 14:49:56 Resting Agitation Score : -1
     2022.12.08 14:49:57 Heartrate : -1 2022.12.08 14:49:57 Resting Agitation Score : -1
     2022.12.08 14:49:58 Heartrate : 32 2022.12.08 14:49:58 Resting Agitation Score : -1
     2022.12.08 14:49:59 Heartrate : 31 2022.12.08 14:49:59 Resting Agitation Score : -1
     2022.12.08 14:50:00 Heartrate : 32 2022.12.08 14:50:00 Resting Agitation Score : -1
     2022.12.08 14:50:01 Heartrate : -1 2022.12.08 14:50:01 Resting Agitation Score : -1
     2022.12.08 14:50:02 Heartrate : -1 2022.12.08 14:50:02 Resting Agitation Score : -1
     2022.12.08 14:50:03 Heartrate : -1 2022.12.08 14:50:03 Resting Agitation Score : -1"""

lines = input_string.split('\n')
for line in lines:
    print(line.split(':')[-1].strip()) # prints items after last ':' without whitespace
```

if you have an input file and want an output file it could look something like this:

```
with open("input.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
lines = file.readlines()

with open("output.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    for line in lines:
        file.write(line.split(':')[-1].strip() + '\n')
```

Comment: It is data directly coming from a sensor